How to use LipeRMI in Android?
I downloaded LipeRMI from their website and managed to successfully add the library to a java project and set up a connection between client and server.
I'm looking for a way to add the LipeRMI to an Android project. It seems that I can't add the folder because it is missing a gradle project file?
the message that I get
I did manage to add the LipeRMI as external library in a java project.
LipeRMI external library

I saw a similar question earlier so this will be more of a why no one uses Java RMI and specifically LipeRMI on Android. 1) The lib hasn't been touched since 2008 same year as Android 1.0 released. Lack of recent update means lack of support from author and community. 2) Searching StackOverflow shows few posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+java+rmi 3) searching github for java-rmi shows that most of the popular projects are for security analysis rather than use: https://github.com/topics/java-rmi 4) If new to Android change to web service as docs/tutorials available.

@MorrisonChang Just wanted to say thank you. I switched to a Spring Boot application and managed to get a perfect grade on the project. This was my final course in BSc Computer Science.
